# Is it natural to say "hold the ball under your chin" or "hold the ball in your neck"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

My hands are full and I can not hold my tennis ball, so I decided to hold the ball by pinching it between my chin and neck as shown in the picture.

Is it natural to say "**I held the ball under my chin**" or "**I held the ball in my neck**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(At least to me as a native American English speaker...) "Under my chin" is more natural.  "In my neck" sounds like it was somehow *inside* the neck itself (that is, under the skin), and doesn't immediately conjure the image of how you were holding it in the same way that "under my chin" does. "*Against* my neck" would sound a bit better, but doesn't convey that you're holding it there with your chin specifically, as opposed to, for example, with your hand.